# RSpec in TextMate: NameError: uninitialized constant RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec-rails, textmate

Trying to use RSpec in Ruby and also with a Rails project. Works fine from the command line, but Cmd-R in TextMate results in `NameError: uninitialized constant RSpec`

`spec/coffee_spec.rb`:

```
class Coffee
  def ingredients
    @ingredients ||= []
  end

  def add(ingredient)
    ingredients << ingredient
  end

  def price
    1.00
  end
end

RSpec.describe 'A cup of coffee' do
  let(:coffee) { Coffee.new }

  it 'costs $1' do
    expect(coffee.price).to eq(1.00)
  end

  context 'with milk' do
    before { coffee.add :milk } 

    it 'costs $1.25' do
      expect(coffee.price).to eq(1.25)
    end
  end
end
```

I first tried to run `coffee_spec.rb` from Marston-Dees in Ruby and had same problem, but also tried in Rails project with same result.

Comment: Sounds like a loading error. What's in your gemfile, `rspec`, or `rspec-rails`? Do you have a `require 'spec_helper'` in a `.rspec` file in your project root by any chance?? Can you try adding `require 'spec_helper'` at the top of that file and running it with your shortcut via Textmate?

Comment: `require 'spec_helper'` >> `LoadError: cannot load such file — spec_helper` 

and gem `rspec-rails`

Answer (score 1):

I just revisited this because it still wasn't working right. This time I fixed it by setting TextMate `PATH` to `$PATH:/usr/local/bin:/usr/texbin:/opt/local/bin`